# Visual Studio GUI mouse cursor flickering between pointer and resize

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

In Visual Studio 2012 I have recently encountered a problem where if I use the GUI designer for adding/removing/modifying items from the toolbox on a form. The cursor flickers insanely between the resize and regular cursor whenever I select a combobox or textbox. I have not removed/added/edited the graphics card or drivers, I've not had any new hardware added or removed so I am not too sure what is happening or why this problem has surfaced itself.

Even the ComboBox tasks (small play button where you add or bind items) flickers insanely. Oddly enough this does not happen with buttons/radio buttons/checklists etc. It has only been happening with ComboBoxes and TextBoxes.

Laptop: Thinkpad T410 Win 7 64bit, intel i5 M 560 2.67GHz, 8gb Ram, Intel HD Graphics, Windows Experience Index rating 4.3.

Comment: Probably to do with the graphics card drivers. I would update them and see if this solves it. The GUI designer doesn't do anything spectacular but renders on the screen however the graphics card engine does it.

Comment: ComboBox also uses the native Edit control so this is related.  Environmental problem of course, you need to go back in memory to when it last ran correctly.  Something kind of program you installed that messes with edit controls.  If you have no idea then maybe you can find it with the debugger.  Start another instance of VS, Tools + Attach to Process to attach to the first, be sure to select the native debugger.  Look in the Debug + Windows + Modules window and look for a weirdo DLL.

Comment: @HansPassant hmmm...I've only installed git. I'll test with uninstalling git and if that doesn't work debugging. Could git be the problem?

Comment: @HansPassant ive attached the vs session to the debug but have no idea what .dll it is in the debug > windows > modules, or do anything after that.

Comment: Hmya, programmers ought to have a pretty good idea what code runs on their machine.  Consider it a learning expedition, spend the time.

Comment: Having the same issue with Visual Studio 2013.  I've tried a variety of approaches (latest nVidia drivers, enabling and disabling hardware rendering in VS, reinstalling VS2013), have you found a solution?  My issue exhibits when VS2013 run in Safe mode (no extensions)

Comment: Another guy with the same problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f825ae92-54d3-4aa0-9bd3-67d587d0e86a/windows-forms-designer-cursor-will-flicker-like-mad-when-a-textbox-combobox-or-listbox-is?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 2):

The link codeLearner provided showed me how to resolve the issue.

> Try turning off per monitor awareness via unchecking Tools->Options->Environment->General->“Optimize rendering for screens…”

Answer (score 1):

Removing Kaspersky Anti-virus resolved this issue for me.  See

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e77b4334-7aa7-45ef-a540-83910f17ce9e/selecting-controls-in-vs2010-windows-forms-designer-and-textbox-menu-flickering?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 1):

I have found a **simple** but great solution for this problem! 
In *Design View* open context menu (with right click) and select *Lock Controls*. Of course this option will restrict some operations in *Design View*, BUT:

**- It stops cursor flickering/flashing

 - It stops object or UI freezing**

This tricky solution worked for me, I hope for you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, opening Visual Studio in primary display/screen has resolved everything. More details [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/scrollbar-scroll-arrows-flickering-when-editing-as/895655#T-N895672) Thanks